# Issue overriding Vuetify styles with my own stylesheets

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am working on a project using Vue2 and Vuetify. 
The main issue is that my Vuetify styles get imported always after my styles.

Tried this :

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-flex>
    <v-card class="myCard"></v-card>
  </v-flex>
</template>

<style>
  .myCard {
      background-color : yellow;
  }
</style>
```

> main.js

```
import App from './Components/App.vue';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

It seems like the style is loaded inside the `<head/>` tag before vuetify styles.

I tried loading changing the order of the imports like this :

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './Components/App.vue';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

This doesn't work.
Also tried importing all the styles in a Main.scss file loading vuetify styles first, then my own stylesheets but that does not work as well.

How can you enforce the order of stylesheets import?

Comment: try to remove it from the `<head/>` and import like this inside your App.js style tag `<style>
  @import './assets/styles/yourstyles.css';
</style>`

Comment: Inspect the v-card and see if vuetify has removed your `myCard` class entirely with javascript. If so, it doesn't matter what order you load them.

Comment: It doesn't remove my class. The issue is that the inner component style tag gets placed in the head tag above vuetify stylesheet, in the Element inspector tab I see my rules getting overriden by vuetify rules

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to my tailwind.config.js file fixed this problem for me.

`module.exports = { important: '#app', }`

It adds a selector to the tailwind classes to increase their importance - but without adding !important to the css rule. In my case, that was enough to take precendence over the Vuetify styles.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy

Comment: Bad idea! Broke my custom styles

Answer (score 1):

Import the vuetify.css file in your main.css above your css content? Or have a main.scss file where you import different css files where you have control of the order of the files like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Roboto+Mono');

@tailwind preflight;
@import 'buttons';
@import 'tables';
@import 'icons';
@import 'checkbox';
@import 'select';
@import 'tabs';
@import 'cards';
@import 'alerts';
@import 'forms';
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: I tried creating a .scss file where I import the vuetify styles first and then my own styles but due to HMR - using style loader for development, the vuetify stylesheet always creates a style tag in the html file after my own styles.